# Git rebase merge branches with different subfolders

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

I had two repositories and then combined them into one, so that each repo is now copied to a branch in a new/third repository.
I also moved all files from one repo into a subfolder, and the other into a different subfolder using filter-branch.

So, branch_A is under folder "A" and "branch_B" is under folder B", and from git's point of view, it has been like that for all time.

I want to combine the two branches into one, so that when I checkout a random commit from the middle of history, I will have both folders.

I can do this with rebase, but critically, I want the commits to retain their author date, *essentially interleaving the histories together*. When I rebase, it just chucks the commits at the end, and all the commits have today's date.

This should be doable because as the branches track different folders, there should be absolutely no conflicts.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be done, yes: but it is not *simple*, and rebase alone is not going to get you there.

(I am sure a bunch of this is stuff you already know, but it's worth going over step by step as a lot of Git documentation leaves a lot to be desired, which leaves gaps in people's understanding.)

Remember that a repository is a collection of commits.  Each commit is—or contains, if we break it down, but let's look at the commits as intact entities for now—a snapshot of a source tree, i.e., some data, plus some information *about* that snapshot, i.e., some metadata.  The commit itself is identified by a unique hash ID.  This hash ID is nothing more than a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.<sup>1</sup>  The checksum itself *cannot* change, as it's just the checksum of that string, and the string itself is not going to change, as that's what makes up the commit.

Now, crucially, in the metadata for each commit, there is a `parent` line:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | grep parent
parent 90d79d71910415387590a733808140e770382b2f
```

That is, each commit contains the actual hash ID of some other, *previous* commit.  Some commits—*merge* commits—contain two or more parent IDs, and at least one commit, a *root* commit, has *no* parent, but most commits have exactly one.

These parent hash IDs have the effect of forming a backwards-looking chain of commits within a repository.  If we start with a nearly-empty repository, with just three commits in it, and call them `A`, `B`, and `C` instead of using their actual big ugly hash IDs, we can draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` is the latest, and it remembers the actual hash ID of its parent `B`.  Commit `B` is the one we made second, and it remembers the actual hash ID of its parent `A`.  Commit `A` is the first, and being first, there was no previous commit for it to remember, so it's the root commit.

If commit hash IDs really were this simple, we could just remember that there are three commits so our latest must be `C`.  But they look and act like random numbers, and they're impossible for us mere humans to remember.  So we have Git use *branch names* to remember the *last* commit in the chain:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

The name `master` remembers the actual hash ID, so that the name `master` *points to* commit `C`.  Meanwhile `C` points to `B` and `B` points to `A`.

If we want to add a *new* commit, we tell Git to extract commit `C` by using the name `master`.  Git remembers that we are "on" branch `master`, by attaching the special name `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we want to add a new commit to a new *branch*, we tell Git: *Make a new branch name `dev`, also pointing to commit `C`, and attach `HEAD` to `dev`.*  Now we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

Now we make a new commit in the usual way.  Git creates the commit by making a snapshot of the source, adding our name and email and the date and so on, and using the hash ID of commit `C` as the parent for a new commit.  The new commit gets a new, random-seeming (but actually totally deterministic, once we have the date-and-time-stamp and our log message and so on) hash ID.  We'll just call it commit `D` though:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

The magic part occurs now: Git updates the *current branch name*—the one to which the special name `HEAD` is attached—by writing the *actual hash ID* of commit `D` into it.  So now the name `dev` points to `D`, while `master` continues to point to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

As we go along adding more commits, at some point we have a situation like this:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- dev
```

We run `git checkout master`, which selects commit `J` and attaches `HEAD` to `master`, and then `git merge dev`.  The merge operation now combines the work on `master`—the changes between commits `H` and `J`—with the work on `dev`, the changes between commits `H` and `L`.  If Git is able to do all the combining on its own, Git makes the final merge commit on its own as well.  This new merge commit `M` has, as its *first* parent, commit `J`: the commit we had checked-out.  It has commit `L`, the one we told Git to merge, as its *second* parent.  As always, Git writes the new hash ID for the new commit into the current branch name, so that `master` now points to the new merge `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master
         \    /
          K--L   <-- dev
```

We can now delete the *name* `dev`, if we wish, as the commits can all be found by starting at `M` and working backwards.  From `M`, we must go backwards through *both* `J` *and* `L`.

Note that if we leave the name `dev` in place, commits through `H`, plus `K` and `L`, are on *both* branches.  All commits in `dev` are also in `master` now.  Commits `I`, `J`, and `M` are *only* in `master`, but the others are in both branches.  Before the merge, commits through `H` were in both branches.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it's a checksum of the literal word `commit`, the size in bytes of the metadata including the tree hash ID string for the data, some spaces and other bytes, and then the bytes of the metadata.  Use `git cat-file -p HEAD` to see an example commit: the checksum is the result of prefixing this with what Python would print if given the formatting directive:

```
b'commit {}\0{}'.format(len(content), content)
```

where `content` contained the byte-string produced by `git cat-file -p` here.

---

#### Fetching from a separate history creates a second root

Let's go back to a nice simple three-commit original repository, with only one branch:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Now let's `git fetch` from another, different, three-commit repository that has one `master` as well.  This gets us `otherrepo/master`, if we use the name `otherrepo` as the name of the remote:

```
git remote add otherrepo <url>
git fetch otherrepo
```

results in:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

D--E--F   <-- otherrepo/master
```

We can make our own branch name for this second branch, rather than using this remote-tracking name `otherrepo/master`.  It does not really matter but it makes our next `git filter-branch` easier, so let's do that:

```
git branch m2 otherrepo/master
```

Now we'll run the `git filter-branch` commands that move everything into sub-directories.  Each such command *copies* some of the original commits to new ones that have different hash ID, and different saved snapshots, but the same author and committer information and the same log messages.  The parent hash IDs point back to the copies, so we wind up with:

```
A--B--C   [abandoned]

A'-B'-C'  <-- master

D--E--F   [abandoned]

D'-E'-F'  <-- m2
```

We don't need the original chains of commits any more, and once we ditch the `refs/original/` names that `git filter-branch` makes, we won't even be able to *find* the originals any more unless we've written their hash IDs down somewhere.  So we can stop drawing them, if we like, and I will (but I'll retain the tick / prime marks on the one-letter commit names, to denote that these are the ones holding the renamed-into-subtree files).

#### What you need now is to invent the desired final graph

You now have:

```
A'-B'-C'  <-- master

D'-E'-F'  <-- m2
```

You would *like* to have, perhaps:

```
A"-E"-B"-F"   <-- master
```

Or maybe you would *like* to have:

```
A"-C"-F"   <-- master
```

Or, maybe it's something else entirely.  It's *pretty* clear, but maybe not totally clear and maybe not actually *true*, that you'd like to have a new root commit, probably this `A"`, that is the result of:

- extracting the tree from `A'` *and* the tree from `D'` into one common tree
- committing that, with a log message from either `A'` or `D'` or maybe both

Following this new `A"` commit, you might want to replace *just* the `D'` sub-tree with *just* the `E'` sub-tree.  Or maybe you would like to replace the `A'` sub-tree with the `B'` sub-tree *and* replace the `D'` sub-tree with the `E'` sub-tree.  Or maybe you want a third combination—this part is *not* at all clear, certainly not to me, and maybe not to you either. :-)

One way or another, though, your job is to figure out which sub-trees you would like to combine, and which commit message(s) you want to combine or use.  You may then make a new commit from that result.  That will be your second commit, that has `A"` as its parent.

This repeats for as many commits as there are in the chains.  If the chains are complex—if `master` points to something with divergences and merges, and/or `m2` points to something with divergences and/or merges, *you* must figure out how you'd like to combine these two histories, including their sub-trees.  It's definitely the case that extracting any `master` commit will affect only the `A` sub-tree, and extracting any `m2` commit will affect only the `B` sub-tree.  But actually taking the commits, in whichever order, and making new commits with whichever parent(s) ... *that* is the hard job you must solve.

Once you figure out *what* you want, it's a relatively simple matter of programming to make it occur.  You could try to use `git filter-branch` to do it, but it may be easier to just do what `git filter-branch` does: set up the right tree and make new commits, using `git write-tree` to write out the index and then `git commit-tree -p <parent> [-p <parent> ...] <tree>` with the right standard-input log message (or a `-F` file with a log message) and the right `GIT_{AUTHOR,COMMITTER}_{NAME,EMAIL,DATE}` strings in the environment to force the author and committer names, email addresses, and date-and-time-stamps on the new commits.  The plumbing command `git commit-tree` will make a new commit and produce, on its standard output, the hash ID of that new commit.  Use that as the parent of the subsequent commit(s) as appropriate, to build up your new chains.

(Note that you can use `git read-tree` to fill in an index for `git write-tree`, and/or you can extract files from commits into a work-tree in a more typical way, then use `git add` to build up a new index to write.  See the filter-branch source—it's just a giant shell script—for some tricks and techniques.)

When you are all done and have built the branch tip commit(s) you want, use `git update-ref` or the more user-oriented `git branch` command to forcibly set particular one or more branch name(s) to hold the hash ID(s) of the desired commit(s).  You now have your reconstructed history, exactly the way you want it.

Comment: You spent so much time discussing how git works and then eventually give general advice but not an actual solution to the very specific question. Maybe if I had a spare few hours, I could use the last three paragraphs of your reply to come up with something. This is more like a long re-wording of my problem than a solution.

Comment: The problem is, your specific question doesn't *have* one specific solution. The main point here is that `rebase` is not the way to go; `filter-branch` is closer, but perhaps something you write yourself, based *on* filter-branch, is better.